# Where are the feed links?

Tags: support, feed

I want to have all meta posts to the site I contribute to put into my feed reader. So I navigate to:

https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions

But there's no link to get any feeds. How can I find the feed I want?

Answer (score 2):

**For the latest 30 posts:**

To get a feed of your specific scenario:

https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/feeds

It seems simply appending `/feeds` to the site you desire will return the last 30 posts.  Additionally, this link can be found at the bottom of the Hot Network Questions list on the home page for the site:

[image: home tab feed link]

**For a Single Post:**

You can get a feed for a single question by navigating to the question and finding the link at the bottom of the Hot Network Questions lists:

[image: question feed]

**For Tags:**

Feeds seem to also exist for tags.  Hover over a tag to a question and you will see this:

[image: tag feed]

Searching for "RSS Feeds" in the help center yields only one [help page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/interesting-topics) that mentions anything about them and it only seems to be about tags.

Comment: These don't really answer the question, I want all posts to Code Review Meta - `https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/feeds`. Another member of this site found it, but their answer was for my user feed and so the comments are deleted (under their answer). I won't upvote this answer as it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @Peilonrayz Have you navigating to the link you just posted?https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/feeds seems to yield what you want actually.  correct me if I am wrong - if so I can update my answer.  I was trying to find the actually RSS feed on the page somewhere rather than just guessing at URLs but it seems that may be it?

Comment: Wat. Yes, like I said it's the link I wanted?!

Comment: @Peilonrayz Did you try clicking on the links circled in red in Timmy's answer? That will produce a popup that shows the link.

Comment: @KodosJohnson this is true - additionally clicking the orange and white RSS feed icon will take you to the actual feed to which you can get the link out of the address bar.

Comment: @KodosJohnson Why would I click on things that clearly aren't what I asked for? Yeah they're feeds, but I wanted a specific feed.

Comment: @Peilonrayz What specific feed are you looking for? If you go to https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/ and click the "Recent questions feed" link, you will get a popup containing the link `https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/feeds`. This is a feed of the recent posts to codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/ which is "meta posts to the site I contribute to " as you said.

Comment: @KodosJohnson Yeah, which was edited in after my comments.

Comment: @Peilonrayz If you are looking for a feed *specifically* for the questions page, there does not appear to be one.  However, after comparing the actual feed to what the Home and Question pages look like, the `/feeds` link above seems to correspond with the Questions Page rather than the Home page of the site despite it being retrieved from the home page.  If this still isn't what your after, then I'm afraid I'm out of thoughts.